# Azure Terraform Network Security Group Association to a Subnet with Modules

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-modules, azure-nsg

I need to create a module based application with Terraform in Azure.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet_network_security_group_association

Basically I need the above but using modules for both the subnet and the network security group like this : (Network security group would contain the association)

```
main.tf (root)
  modules
     networksecuritygroup
         main.tf
         variable.tf
     subnet
         main.tf
         output.tf
         variable.tf
```

I am not sure how to create a reference at the subnet_id section of the network security group association at the NSG module to the already existing subnet module's subnet ID.

This part gets me thinking :

```
subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.example.id
```

Should look something like this maybe?

```
subnet_id = var.subnetname.id?
```

I can't get it work and I couldn't find anything similar like this, only a resource group and storage account association but that is different as no ID needed there...

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to create a reference at the subnet_id section of the network security group association at the NSG module to the already existing subnet module's subnet ID.

Alternatively ,You can associate **NSG** with existing **Subnet ID** using terraform, you can use data block for using existing `Subnet`.

```
        provider "azurerm" {
          features {}
        }
        
        data "azurerm_subnet" "venkatsubnet" {
          name                 = "samplesubnet"
          virtual_network_name = "Demosubnet"
          resource_group_name  = "<rg-name>"
        }
        
     # If you want to use an existing Virtual Network instead of creating a new Virtual Network, use the below data block for the Virtual Network.
    
   #data "azurerm_virtual_network" "example"    {
         # name                = "Demosubnet"
          #resource_group_name = "<rg-name>"
        #}
        
        resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
          name                = "example-network"
          address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
          location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.location
          resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.name
        }
        
        resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "samplensg" {
          name                = "example-nsg"
          location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.location
          resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.name
        
          security_rule {
            name                       = "test123"
            priority                   = 100
            direction                  = "Inbound"
            access                     = "Allow"
            protocol                   = "Tcp"
            source_port_range          = "*"
            destination_port_range     = "*"
            source_address_prefix      = "*"
            destination_address_prefix = "*"
          }
        }
        
        resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
          subnet_id                 = data.azurerm_subnet.venkatsubnet.id
          network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.samplensg.id
        }
        
        output "subnet_id" {
          value = data.azurerm_subnet.venkatsubnet.id
        }
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

After running the above code, the **Subnet** is associated with the **NSG** in portal as shown below.

[image]

Reference:  [Azure network - Subnet](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/claranet/subnet/azurerm/latest).

Comment: Thanks but my issue is with modules, I can't refer to an already existing subnet resource if that is within the module called subnet... :(